# spark scala dataframe adding 1 to all the values in a column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

i am new to spark dataframe .i have a text file having data like

```
schoolid,classid,studentid,subject,marks
bjs,5,111,hindi,23
bjs,5,222,maths,78
bjs,7,333,bio,89
bjs,1,444,chemistry,67
ghs,2,555,bio,78
ghs,2,666,phy,56
ghs,9,777,drawing,56
```

i want to convert this data to dataframe and add 1 to each of the values under marks column

so code I am using is

```
val df = sparkSession.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load("samplefile1.txt")
 val newdf = df.select(col($"marks"+1)).show()
```

but the error that I am getting is

```
type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.sql.Column required: String
```

can I have help with the correct syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 df.withColumn("marks", expr("marks +1").cast("integer")).show
```

Output :

```
+--------+-------+---------+---------+-----+
|schoolid|classid|studentid|  subject|marks|
+--------+-------+---------+---------+-----+
|     bjs|      5|      111|    hindi|   24|
|     bjs|      5|      222|    maths|   79|
|     bjs|      7|      333|      bio|   90|
|     bjs|      1|      444|chemistry|   68|
|     ghs|      2|      555|      bio|   79|
|     ghs|      2|      666|      phy|   57|
|     ghs|      9|      777|  drawing|   57|
+--------+-------+---------+---------+-----+
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution:

```
df.withColumn("marks",col("marks") + lit(1)).show
```